# What happens if the Winter Soldier commands himself?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics

The Winter Soldier can be programmed using Russian words, making him comply with whoever speaks those in front of him. What would happen if he, himself, speaks those words? Will he go into an infinite coma or he will be doing random stuff whatever comes to his mind? What could be the possible outcomes?

Has this been covered in any canon Marvel works? Be it comics or cinematic?

Comment: His head explodes.

Comment: :D :D I don't think that this scenario would be directly covered in any marvel comics, (Its not in MCU atleast) , But knowing views of Marvel Comics enthusiasts would be interesting.

Comment: @Valorum [His head a splode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mrb2Oc6naDI)

Answer (score 8):

In the comics (*Captain America* (2004) #14), James Barnes was freed from his Russian programming by Steve Rogers, when Steve had access to a (partial, I think) cosmic cube.

[image: Cap restores Bucky (*Captain America* (2004) #14)]

Since then, there's been no evidence that there are any "command codes" or the like that can revert him to his former Russian programming - despite the fact that this should have simply restored his memories.

We are left to assume that having his full identity back was enough to either erase any "deep programming", or that such programming was deemed unnecessary, since James *didn't* have an intact identity.

Comment: Well in the MCU, Command codes are shown which brings back the Winter Soldier as programmed by the Russians. He even gets back to cryosleep at Wakanda so that he can't be misused again. If we take that into consideration, what could be the outcomes?

Comment: That, would be a different answer. This one covers the comics, which you indicated an interest in.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that there's a strong theory that The Winter Soldier wasn't Bucky, but that the Cube acted on Steve's subconscious desire to overwrite him into being Bucky.